# What Happens on Shiny runApp()?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a login page. Once the user has logged in, it directs them to the rest of the app.

As I have been developing my shiny app, the time it takes to render the initial login page has been increasing (it is now around 30 seconds).

I have put breakpoints all over my code (including the first lines of ui.R, server.R, and other files which are sourced).

The login screen is similar to that of [this](http://withr.me/blog/2014/01/03/authentication-of-shiny-server-application-using-a-simple-method/) great post from Huidong Tian.

**What is shiny doing for 30 seconds between me doing `runApp()`, and
   hitting the first breakpoint on the first line of my code**?

The console simply prints:
`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:xxxx`, and then waits.

I hope the question is generic enough such that code isn't needed - and I'm not sure what code could help answer the question. Let me know if further info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: See the [Execution section on this page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/). Do you have code outside the `shinyServer()` call? Or lots of code inside that call and not in a reactive element?

Comment: Thanks, I will read that and test further.  I do have lots of code inside shinyServer() in various elements.  From what you're saying, does this mean breakpoints aren't triggered when the app is initially launched?  Thanks

Comment: How many lines is your server.R? I know that my dashboard app has 9k lines if put into one file (So I spread it and sourced those blocks). You should also source you files, it should improve the rendering via renderUI to create the page once logged in...

Comment: Thanks all.  I have sourced, and further utilised reactive expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to the original question:**  (this is as I have observed, please comment / edit if incorrect)

When I do `runApp()`, RStudio compiles the all the code within the application, and no breakpoints are triggered.

Once the entire code is compiled (ie reactive expressions stored in the memory, packages loaded), breakpoints are triggered on lines of code as they are hit.

**Why my code was slow before first breakpoint**

Reactive expression wasn't properly used on the big database call, and I have now sourced much of my code to other files which has improved the speed greatly.

I have also discovered the fantastic function `reactivePoll()` which has helped.